# Symfony2 Custom Doctrine Type

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to create a new Symfony2 / Doctrine type for my db
We shall call this dbmd5. I already have a working custom function in mssql server 2008

```
myfunc(arg1, arg2)
```

Now i need to make doctrine call this automaticly with both arguments that represent different columns in my entity. Like email and username for example.
I need script to call it

```
myfunc(email, username);
```

How can i link "username" to this type i've given to "email"

Column declaration in entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="dbmd5")
 */
protected $email;
```

I have also created my custom type and added it to the Types pool
My convertToDatabaseValueSQL:

```
public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform) {

    $usernameColumn = '';//how do i get the username value>
    $value = sprintf('[dbo].[myfunc](%s, %s)', $sqlExpr, $usernameColumn);
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My sollution

Add to Entity:

```
protected static $stored = array();

public function store($name)
{
    self::$stored[$name] = $this;
}

public static function stored($name)
{
    return self::$stored[$name];
}
```

In controller initiate the Entity

```
$entity = new Entity();
```

Before persisting the entity in entity manager, store the data

```
   $entity->store('storeName');
```

In dbmd5 type declaration, add

```
public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform) {        
    $entity = Entity::stored('storeName');        
    return sprintf("[dbo].[myfunc](?, '".addslashes($entity->username)."')", $sqlExpr);
}
```

It's extremly messy and it only covers my needs. 
I am willing to improve my code if you give me valid suggestions.

Best regards,